# Ubuntu installation is not proceeding after 'Allocate Drive Space' step

Tags: 14.04

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04.3 alongside Windows 7.
I followed installation instructions from Ubuntu website: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop
But after step 4 (Allocate Drive Space) install process does not proceed.

Comment: Which of the given suggestions did you choose ?

Comment: I have chosen Install along with Windows

Comment: Please boot from ubuntu install media and select 'Try Ubuntu'. Then open GParted and provide a screenshot from your partition layout.

Comment: file:///home/ubuntu/Desktop/Screenshot%20from%202015-09-11%2022:35:53.png

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0BzkSi7ARULcUJnTGRtaGYyX1U/view?usp=sharing    Please find the attached of gparted snap shot

Comment: I have tried to attach image file , As I am new to ubuntu and forum , I dont have sufficent reputations to post image.. So I have shared through google Drive

Comment: Thank you - I checked it - your disk seems to have a serious problem - I am very sorry to tell you that you have to completely rebuild your disk. That means you have to create a new partition table, reinstall Windows (if you want) and then install ubuntu. Do you know exactly how to perform this ?

Comment: I known how to re-install windows and install ubuntu.... I will do it and update you....  Thank you very much for assistance... I am new to this type of work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the screenshot shows your hard disk is corrupted.
You have to completely rebuild your hard disk drive.

Then you can reinstall Windows and install Ubuntu.
So please follow these steps one after the other :

- Save your personal data.
- Boot from Ubuntu install media.
- Select 'Try Ubuntu without installing'.
- Open GParted.
- Click on 'Device' in the application menu.
- Select 'Create Partition Table'.
- If you have an UEFI based BIOS select 'gpt'.
- If you have a legacy BIOS select 'mbr'.
- Boot from Windows install media.
- Install Windows.
- Boot from Ubuntu install media.
- Open GParted.
- Reduce the Windows partition.
- Start Ubuntu installation.
- Choose 'Something else'.
- Select the unallocated space.

For further information : There are some other possibilities to prepare disks and partitions, but I chose this method to assure it will  provide the most easiest way for you to accomplish your goal.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of the answer, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)

Comment: Dear Friend,                                                                                                            I  appreciate you concern. Thank you very much for support and solving the problem . There is a small correction " In the step -> Select 'Create Partition Table'. Value for partition table = unrecognized, and  rest of the step as preferred in above answer